# Regex multiple captures

Tags: regex

I have the following set of IP and PORT numbers I need to capture. Ideally, I would like to capture each IP/PORT combination in their own group for a total of six groups.

I can get the first set split out with this:

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})

server 198.51.100.90:80 weight=3;
server 198.51.100.91:80;
server 198.51.100.93:80;
```

https://regex101.com/r/gS1hR6/1

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/lL8iQ0/1 (add the `g` modifier)

Comment: That did the trick, but it turns out that: one I can't use modifiers in ServiceNow, two ServiceNow loops through the results. :)

Comment: Perhaps you could split the string into new lines to avoid needing a modifier

Answer (score 0):

add the `/g` modifier

> **g modifier:** **g**lobal. All matches (don't return on first match)

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/gS1hR6/2

**Match Information**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [11-24] `198.51.100.90`
2.  [25-27] `80`
MATCH 2
1.  [49-62] `198.51.100.91`
2.  [63-65] `80`
MATCH 3
1.  [78-91] `198.51.100.93`
2.  [92-94] `80`
```

**RegEx**

```
/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})/g
```